# Bitbucket - Retrieve a pull-request's tasks by REST api

Tags: bitbucket

I am assuming this is not possible but hoping it is.

I am using https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/ and trying to retrieve all tasks for a particular pull-request, but I can't figure out how.

Is it possible on Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org)?

Comment: I have to ask: are you trying to work with Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or Bitbucket Server (self-hosted)?

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible - as I type this, the API returns the count of open tasks for a given PR (task_count in https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests/%7Bpull_request_id%7D), but not the content of those tasks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not documented but, it works by sending GET call to below endpoint

`https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/TEAM/REPO_SLUG/pullrequests/PR_ID/tasks`